# UITableView with autolayout does not fill screen in Landscape Mode. Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView. The hosting UIViewController is presented by a UINavigationController. I am using autolayout and have used "Leading Space to Superview (-16.00)" and similar "Trailing Space to Superview Constraint" to pin the tableview to the left and right side of the parent view. It works great in Portrait mode. But when I switch to Landscape mode, the tableview is short by a few pixels on each side. Screen captures are shown below. Notice the small red border on the Landscape version. (I have set the background of the view, under the UITableview, to red.) I can even see this border in the storyboard, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

My app is built for iOS 10 if it matters.

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

Comment: UIController? What do you mean, `UINavigationController` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: It is a UIViewController presented from within a UINavigationController. I have edited my question to be more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Leading Space to Superview

I'm going to suggest that you've pinned the leading/trailing edges to the superview's *margins*. You want to pin them to the superview *itself* (and change the `constant` value to `0`).

Comment: HI Matt, this is the second time in just a few days that you have helped me out. I'm going to have buy your book!